# How disable boot splash screen on Dell XPS 13 Ubuntu 14.04?

Tags: 14.04, boot, grub2, dell, plymouth

Since my Dell XPS 13 failed to boot a few times lately i think some hardware begins to fail. So i would like to see all boot messages.

I already removed quiet and splash from `/etc/default/grub` which now looks like this

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="pcie_aspm=force radeon.modeset=0 nouveau.modeset=0 crashkernel=384M-:128M crashkernel=384M-:128M crashkernel=384M-:128M acpi_osi=\"Windows 2013\" crashkernel=384M-:128M"
```

and using `update-grub` doesn't change anything.
Then I tried to enable

```
GRUB_TERMINAL=console
GRUB_GFXMODE=text
```

which didn't help either.

I also tried to

```
mv /etc/init/plymouth.conf /etc/init/plymouth.conf.disabled
```

again with no change. Moving all `/etc/init/plymouth-*.conf` to `plymouth-...conf.disabled` gives boot messages but the system doesn't finish  booting. I only get to a line

```
activating power saving .... done
```

(or something) and nothing more. So I needed to boot into safe mode and undo my .disabled changes.

Using synaptic I tried to remove Plymouth but this seems to also remove nearly all installed packages so I didn't continue here.

So, I don't know what else I should try.
Anyone has an idea on how I can get all boot messages including early kernel messages?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a last try I had a look in /boot for the term `splash` which showed that quiet splash has been added to the end of my grub settings.
So I ran

> grep -R splash

in `/etc` which listed a script

> default/grub.d/40_oem-add-missing-default.cfg

```
# in case "quiet splash" is missing
# e.g. (LP: #1304155)

for __i__ in "quiet" "splash"; do
       echo "$GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT" | \
               grep -q -w "$__i__" >/dev/null 2>&1 || \
               GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="$GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT $__i__"
done
unset __i__
```

Bingo. This script adds quiet and splash in case it is removed - dafuq!

Anyway I just commented the script line by line, ran `sudo update-grub` and now I see all boot messages.